# CSS Navbar stuck behind DIV

Tags: css, html

I've been trying to get multiple background images on my page but I couldn't get more than 2, so I started to think that I might use divs instead. But when I use divs I got like 5 white pixels left at the top and and sides of the screen, that was until I changed the position to absolute but then my navbar was stuck behind the div... If anyone could please help me fixing my issue.

My code isn't that good, but this is what I have at the moment:

```css
#P1Tekstvlak1_1 {
  background-image: url("DakB1.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}


/** — Navbar —*/

#nav {
  color: FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#nav_wrapper {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #B50B26;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}

#nav ul li a,
visited {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="nav_wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="TDPD.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="TDPD.html">Over</a></li>
      <li><a href="TDPD.html">Renovatie</a></li>
      <li><a href="TDPD.html">Nieuwbouw</a></li>
      <li><a href="TDPD.html">Vacatures</a></li>
      <li><a href="TDPD.html">WKA</a></li>
      <li><a href="TDPD.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the absolute positioning and then apply a CSS reset like the one [here](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) . Browsers have some styling attributes it applies by default for accessibility purposes. You should remove them. I do this before starting to build any web UI.

Note: Absolute positioning will stack elements versus applying layout to them. That is why you are seeing it behind your NAV